# How can I stop jenkins.pid in fedora15?

Tags: linux, fedora-15, daemon, pid

I have jenkins running, but I need to stop it. in `/var/run` I have `jenkins.pid` which is what the standard jenkins script uses to stop jenkins. The jenkins script uses start-stop-daemon which doesn't seem to exist in fedora15. My system also does not find daemon which I read would be a fedora replacement for start-stop-daemon.

I am not good with Linux terminology. I did find the daemon function defined in `/etc/init.d/functions` but I don't know how to run it.

Can I run it or can I use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `service jenkins stop` as root. You can use the `su -` command to access a root shell. See [The Fedora Basics FAQ](http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/) for more information.

Comment: So anything pid in linux is a service?

Comment: @Rythmic: The jenkins.pid file contains the process ID number that Jenkins runs as. You could try killing Jenkins using a command like `xargs kill < /var/run/jenkins.pid`, but it is better to use the distribution's or service's own tool (as described above) if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
chkconfig jenkins off
```

to make it permanent - so it won't run next time you boot.